# The import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE cannot be resolved

Tags: android, eclipse, ksoap2, android-ksoap2

I downloaded ksoap2 from [this link](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ksoap2/files/ksoap2/2.1.2/ksoap2-j2me-core-2.1.2.jar/download?_test=goal):

after importing the downloaded .jar file into an Android project in Eclipse, I got import error for only the first import line (HttpTransportSE). I searched but nobody else has had/posted this issue. How could this be? thanks!

```
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE; //ERROR:The import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE cannot be resolved
import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
```

Answer (score 6):

You've downloaded the J2ME package, but HttpTransportSE is part of the J2SE jar file.

Shouldn't `ksoap2-j2se-full-2.1.2.jar` work just fine with Android?

Answer (score 4):

Use this library its specific for android and it worked for me (Ksoap2-j2se-full didn't work for me as well)

http://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/

Answer (score 1):

You should use **ksoap2-android-assembly-2.6.3-jar-with-dependencies.jar** file. 
visit http://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/wiki/HowToUse?tm=2

Answer (score 0):

You will Have to add it to Library. (I am using Android Studio)

Right click the library file in the Android Studio(shown under project_name/app/libs/  -> there will an option "Add As Library",
select that

Then A dialogue box will appear where you will have to Select the Module

Thats IT! :)