# Unable to use ksoap2 with Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, soap, ksoap2

I want to use the library ksoap2 for sending and receiving SOAP messages in Android but I'm unable to get it to work in Eclipse. It keeps giving me the message `SoapObject cannot be resolved to a type`. I copied the code of the class `Soap` which I got from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6910000/1323666) (to get it to work first and edit it later to my needs) and used the imports from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7606963/1323666). I'm not very experienced with Android developing,  Java and Eclipse so I'm probably overlooking something.

```
package com.example.myapp;  
import android.content.Context; 
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;
import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope; 
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject; 
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;

public class Soap {
    Context context;    
    int viPeriod;
    String vsUserID;
    String NAMESPACE = "http://localhost/soap/";
    String SOAP_ACTION = "http://localhost/soap/bin/SOAP.dll";
    String METHOD_NAME = "SOAP";    
    public String result = null;
    Object resultRequestSOAP = null;

    public Soap(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public void SendSoap() {
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);    
        request.addProperty("viPeriod", viPeriod);
        request.addProperty("vsUserID", vsUserID);  
        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);

        envelope.dotNet = true;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);  
        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
        androidHttpTransport.debug = true;

        try {
            androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
            String requestDumpString = androidHttpTransport.requestDump;
            System.out.println("requestDump : " + requestDumpString);

            resultRequestSOAP = envelope.getResponse(); // Output received
            result = resultRequestSOAP.toString(); // Result string

            System.out.println("OUTPUT : " + result);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

In the libs folder of the project in Eclipse 4.2.2 is the file `ksoap2-android-assembly-3.0.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar`.
[image: Java Build Path Libraries] 
[image: Java Build Path Order and Export]

What am I doing wrong? Could you point me to the right direction? Or maybe advice me to solve this differently.

Thanks in advance, Dediqated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you added ksoap2 jar file in lib folder, move it to libs folder and then clean the project. This will resolve the issue.

Comment: no I downloaded it straight into the libs folder. I just cleaned the project but still the same problem..

Answer (score 0):

SoapAction should contain namespace and method name.

eg: NAMESPACE ="http://sample/";

METHOD_NAME = "sampleMethod";

SOAP_ACTION = NAMESPACE + METHOD_NAME;

check wether the response is of soap primitive or soap object.

Comment: Well this doesn't solve anything because Eclipse doesn't find the SoapObject. It only shows a squiggly line underneath it..

Comment: Have you created libs folder if yout adt is 17 refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10030233/exception-while-using-ksoap2-android

Comment: I already had the libs folder when creating the project. I'm only using Eclipse for about two months so I have version 21.1 of ADT